# How to create a new clean branch according to the original repo provided that a previous folking exists

Tags: git

Suppose that I have folked a repo called `repo` with only one branch `master` and have modified the code of the repo for a completely different work.

But now I find some typos in the original repo. How can I create a new clean branch according to the original repo so that I can pull requests to fix these typos?

Comment: What branch did you commit your changes to, if any?

Comment: Currently I have only one branch called `master`. I want to create a new branch called, say, `typos`.@choroba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the remote is called `origin`, you can switch to a new branch `typos` based on its `master` branch:

```
git checkout -b typos origin/master
```

Don't forget to `commit` or `stash` your previous changes first.